# IBM Worklight buid all and deploy - "Permission Denied"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to run IBM worklight (Developer Edition-Free) for the very first time on a mac machine other than mine.I have already set up worklight on my mac and it seems to work fine without any errors but when I try to do that on another machine I am getting this error during when I try to do Build all and deploy on a newly created project,

[image]

Any help is appreciated. FYI: there is no admin access for the current user.

Comment: Admin access should not be required. Can you provide a little more information? Is this the Developer Edition of Worklight (free edition) or the Consumer or Enterprise edition (paid editions)? Are you following the basic steps in the Getting Started modules or have you modified the configuration? You mention it happens on a machine other than yours; does this work on your own machine or has it worked in any other environment?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that you are [lacking execute permissions](http://cycling74.com/forums/topic/permission-denied-error13/) in your account for either all or some files/folders. If you do not have admin access, ask your administrator to fix (add) the missing execute permission.